# How can I use the webadmin interface with an embedded Neo4j 2.0 instance?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a project which has been running with an embedded Neo4j 1.8.2 plus web admin interface.

Now I updated the project to run with the latest Neo4j 2.0.1. Although there were some obstacles during that course (as I'm utilizing Spring Data Neo4j) in the end everything went smooth.

But currently I'm stuck in getting the web admin running with it.

Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Here's my config which I was using for the 1.8 version

(class for configuration referenced in the snippets)

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.MapConfiguration;
import org.neo4j.server.configuration.Configurator;
import org.neo4j.server.configuration.ThirdPartyJaxRsPackage;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Neo4jServerConfig implements Configurator {

    private Configuration config;

    public Neo4jServerConfig(Map<String, String> config) {
        this.config = new MapConfiguration(config);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getDatabaseTuningProperties() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ThirdPartyJaxRsPackage> getThirdpartyJaxRsClasses() {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ThirdPartyJaxRsPackage> getThirdpartyJaxRsPackages() {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }

}
```

And the bean definitions
        
        
        
            
                
                
                
                
                
                
            
        
        
    ...
    ...
    
        
            
                
                
            
        
    
    ...
    ...

As mentioned ... this works as expected for the 1.8 embedded Neo4j.

But initialization under Neo4j 2.0 changed quite a bit. So I was forced to use the following bean definitions to get things running again

```
        <!-- neo4j server configuration -->
    <util:map id="neo4jConfig">
        <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
        <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="true"/>
        <entry key="online_backup_enabled" value="true"/>
        <entry key="node_auto_indexing" value="true"/>
        <entry key="node_keys_indexable" value="id,name,type,__type__"/>
        <entry key="relationship_auto_indexing" value="true"/>
    </util:map>

    <bean id="graphDbFactory" class="org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory"/>

    <bean id="graphDbBuilder" factory-bean="graphDbFactory" factory-method="newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${neo4j.db.path}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-bean="graphDbBuilder" factory-method="setConfig">
        <constructor-arg ref="neo4jConfig"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-method="newGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown" />
```

After that I get error markers in this bean definition

```
    <bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDatabaseService" /> 
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="config"/>
    </bean>
```

First, the "org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper" is now deprecated - are there any alternatives, I can use?

And secondly it complains about wrong constructor-arg "graphDatabaseService" ... it says "bean must be of org.neo4j.kernel.GraphDatabaseAPI" (which is also deprecated)

The server starts (at least what I can see from my jetty logs) without errors, but trying to browse to localhost:28473 ends up with no response.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you setting org.neo4j.server.webserver.port to 28473 and overriding the default port 7474?

Answer (score 3):

WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper & GraphDatabaseAPI are deprecated, but there is no alternitve for now ... So you have to use them.

For you, this a sample code of my application, where webadmin is started with an embedded neo4j 2.0.1 server :

```
val graphdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
          .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DBPath)
          .loadPropertiesFromFile(neo4jPropertiesPath)
          .newGraphDatabase()
          .asInstanceOf[GraphDatabaseAPI}

val srv = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper(graphdb, config);
srv.start()
```

So you must cast your "graphDatabaseService" to "GraphDatabaseAPI".
Sorry I don't khnow how to this with spring ... but you can do a wrapper of WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper with the good type.

Cheers

Comment: My question is actually not really dealing with the deprecated classes - this was more or less a side question. Rather I'm looking for a way to get the web interface running. As mentioned previously, the server starts and the web interface registers in my jetty. But as soon as I try to call it, nothing happens. In regards to that, I could imagine, that there is now an alternative way to instanciate it correctly. But thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 3):

Took me longer than I care to admit to get this working. Please take a look at [this pom](https://github.com/monowai/auditbucket/blob/master/ab-engine/pom.xml) for the dependencies, basically 2 includes for neo4j-server and 2 for Jersey. You also have to config the WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper (deprecated).

My POM excludes the CH.QOS logging stuff from Neo4J in favour of my own log configuration.

I've used Spring as well and have externalised most of the config. You can see that file [here](https://github.com/monowai/auditbucket/blob/master/ab-engine/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/neo4j-java.xml).

Once that little lot is done, simply access localhost on port 7474.

```
<util:map id="config">
    <entry key="remote_shell_enabled" value="true"/>
</util:map>

<bean id="graphDbFactory" class="org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory"/>

<bean id="graphDbBuilder" factory-bean="graphDbFactory" factory-method="newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder">
    <constructor-arg value="${neo4j.datastore}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-bean="graphDbBuilder" factory-method="setConfig">
    <constructor-arg ref="config"/>
</bean>

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-method="newGraphDatabase"
      destroy-method="shutdown"/>

<bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper" init-method="start"
      destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and efforts to get this running. But unfortunately it didn't help for me ... :(

Comment: Hmmm, I've just tried this on a from scratch build on Windows (I usually use OSX). browser definitely pops up for me when I go straight to localhost:7474. You can also go to localhost:7474/browser

What URL are you trying to access and what error (if any) do you see?

BTW, the reason for the two neo4j-server includes is one for the browser interface and the other for Neo4j embedded.

Comment: We had to match the exact version of Jersey required by neo4j-server, and include each of these Jersey components, and then to a clean-rebuild before it worked.  We use SBT:
    "org.neo4j.app" % "neo4j-server" % neo4jVersion,
    "org.neo4j.app" % "neo4j-server" % neo4jVersion classifier "static-web",
    "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.18.1",
    "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-server" % "1.18.1",
    "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-servlet" % "1.18.1"

Answer (score 0):

So verified this on OSX;  Just to be clear once you add the POM updates and the spring configuration, that is all you need to do.  Then just browsing to localhost:7474 gives you your object graph.